# How do I return entire values from php as json formats?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

We have a php file called getBuilds.php. When you run this file, it queries the database and returns entire values encoded in json format. Below is sample data:

```
   [
    {
     "BuildingDisplay":"132 Mitchell Street - 132 Mitchell St., SW",
    "BuildingID":"B610012",
    "Address":"132 Mitchell St., SW",
    "City":"Chicago",
    "District":"Central",
    "Location":"B610012 132 Mitchell Street ",
    "State":"IL",
    "StreetName":"132 Mitchell St., SW",
    "Zip":"30303",
    "X":2227970.4292704,
    "Y":1364292.9044986
   },
   {
    "BuildingDisplay":"34 Peachtree Street - 34 Peachtree St.",
    "BuildingID":"B630012",
    "Address":"34 Peachtree St.",
    "City":"Chicago",
    "District":"Central",
    "Location":"B630012 34 Peachtree Street",
    "State":"IL",
    "StreetName":"34 Peachtree St.",
    "Zip":"30303","X":2228810.0213674,
    "Y":1365970.5523757},
    Etc
    etc
  ]
```

Then I am using the following jQuery/Ajax to return just the BuildingID in json format and then populating a dropdownlist with values for BuildingID:

```
 function getBuildings() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'services/getBuilds.php',
    dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(buildingInfo) {
    $(buildingInfo).each(function(i, building) {
    $('<option>').val(building.BuildingID).text(building.BuildingDisplay).appendTo( $('#buildingID') );
          })
    });
    }
```

This works great but we have been asked to pull not just the building ID but all values from the PHP file and return them all as json formats.

This way, we still get dropdownlist populated with BuildingID but populate the rest as hidden values.

I know how to populate the json data as hidden form values but I am not sure how to return all rows of data as json formats.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

I will be more than happy to clarify if needed.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It looks to me as if the PHP code is *already* sending all the stuff to the client (where your existing jQuery code runs).  You're picking out some particular pieces of information, so all you need to do is pick out the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have what you need. Just use jQuery to create some hidden inputs. Also, take note that the code here is more streamlined and optimized for performance because `.each()` performs about 50% slower than a native `for()` loop.

```
function getBuildings() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'services/getBuilds.php',
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (buildingInfo) {

        // get number of items in array given by PHP
        var buildings_count = buildingInfo.length;

        // start an array to hold re-arranged buildings array
        var newBuildingInfo = [];

        // loop buildings
        for (var i = 0; i < buildings_count; i += 1) {

            // append an <option> tag to your <select>
            $('#buildingID').append('<option value="' + buildingInfo[i].BuildingID + '">' + buildingInfo[i].BuildingDisplay + '</option>');

            // set the key value to BuildingID so that it is easily referenced later
            newBuildingInfo['' + buildingInfo[i].BuildingID + ''] = buildingInfo[i];

            // using single-quotes in newBuildingInfo['' + buildingInfo[i].BuildingID+ ''] is important
            // if a BuildingID is 000432, notice the starting zeros, then things will get funky

        }

        // Listen for the value of the <select> to change
        $('#buildingID').on('change', function () {

            // This code assumes you already have these hidden inputs available on the form before this Javascript is ever used
            // Set the value of the hidden fields based on the <select>'s ID choosing the corret array element
            $('input[name="Address"]').val(newBuildingInfo[''+$(this).val()+''].Address);
            $('input[name="City"]').val(newBuildingInfo[''+$(this).val()+''].City);
            $('input[name="District"]').val(newBuildingInfo[''+$(this).val()+''].District);
            // etc...

        });
    });
}
```

Comment: this is precisely what I needed.

You are awesome and thank you for your kindness and for putting up with my explanations.

Just one more silly question, do I need to manually added each hidden form to the actual form?

For instance, do I need to do something like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="building[' + i + '][Address]" value="' + buildingInfo[i].Address + '">` because I don't see the values in the form when I viewed source.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Since Javascript lives on the page itself, any changes to HTML will not show up when simply viewing source code via Ctrl+U or whatever. I recommend Right-Clicking on the very first input field of your form and selecting "Inspect Element" which will bring up a console window. This window is the actual DOM tree as interpreted by your browser and manipulated by Javascript. Now find the opening `<form>` tag and you will see the hidden inputs directly after it =)

Comment: I am using both FF and IE 9.

I see the values from the dropdowns, buildingID, etc. but not the hidden values.

Comment: I recommend FireFox or Chrome for this. IE isn't too helpful when inspecting elements in the way I described above

Comment: I am actually using firefox.

I believe there is a way I can see the values.

We have a summary page that displays all selected or entered form values. Below is an example:

`<p>Floor: <span id="summFloor"></span></p>`

So, let's say we would like to show value for City on this summary page, what do I need to change to get it to display?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I would have to see some code for the summary page before I can provide any useful guidance. Go ahead and update your question with some code if you wish. I still highly recommend learning about the method I described in my second comment.

Comment: Ahh, I see the values. Here is an example of one:

`<input type="hidden" value="Chicago" name="building[487][City]"></input>`

The only question I have about this is why is the name reading like this?

Instead of name="City"..., it reads:

`name="building[487][City]"`.

How can I remove `building[487]`?

You are awesome!

Yes, I used the inspector as you recommended.

Comment: Well if you give every hidden city input a `name="city"` then submitting the form will only give you the very last hidden city input. Overall I think the flow of what you're doing is a bit incorrect. I don't think you should put all those values into hidden fields but rather your summary page should take the BuildingID from your select and run another query to pull the rest of the data you need.

Comment: In PHP you would access `name="building[487][City]"` by doing this `echo $_POST['building'][487]['City'];` and `echo $_POST['building'][487]['Address'];` and so forth...

Comment: Here is a PHP snippet I absolutely love for debugging arrays `echo '<div style="background-color:white; padding:15px;"><pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre></div>';` try it out on your summary page

Comment: I see, so you are looking to only pass the associated data of the BuildingID selected. That can be worked into the answer I provided. I'll let you know when the update is ready

Comment: I didn't want to keep quiet till I am done.

I am working on it and will update you shortly.

Thanks alot for your kindness and patience.

Comment: it is WORKING perfectly!

You are surely a blessing and may you be rewarded ten fold for your patience and generously sharing your knowledge and assistance.

Thank you very, vey much.

PERFECT!

Comment: You are very welcome, I'm glad to see you appreciate the answer so much! We were all noobs at one point or another =) would you care to also upvote my answer? It won't be ten-fold but more like 1.66 fold :p

Comment: More than happy to do so. That's the least I could do.

Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I know this thread is closed but just one more thing if possible, please.

This is how form fields are defined on the form:

`  <input name="City" id="City" type="hidden" value="" />`

As you know, we can't see the value unless we use firefox inspector.

Is there a way to display the value on SAME page/form?

If you can't answer or you have had enough, that's perfectly understandable.

Comment: Lol, I can show you. I assume you would not want these fields to be editable? Viewing purposes only?

Comment: No, I don't want them viewable or editable. I am just doing it because I have demo this afternoon and rather than create a separate php page to display them, I am wondering if they could be done on same page. 

Otherwise, I create a separate page and display them there.

Comment: Your response is a bit confusing because you want to "display the value on SAME page/form" but then you say "I don't want them viewable" but maybe this will help: make the fields text inputs like so `<input name="City" id="City" type="text" value="" />` and make them `readonly` like this `<input name="City" id="City" type="text" value="" readonly />`

Comment: Oh so that's all I need?

I could have done that. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.

You have given me a lot more than I asked for/deserved.

Many, many thanks.

Comment: Lol I figured something was being over-complicated again. The reason you would want to make it `readonly` is so that the values cannot be changed before going to the summary page. Good luck!